# Updating an entity through database procedure and reading updated entity in spring transaction

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a simple structure Controller - Service - Repository.

I have an issue with executing Oracle procedure that updates an entity and immediately calling a read database function. The entity that read function returns is an old entity, before it was updated.

This is not a problem if the Service method is not annotated with @Transactional, but in that case I can see the updated value in database immediately after executing update procedure.

Answer (score 0):

When a method is transactional it does not immediately commit the updates to the database, So immediate read does not reflect the updated values.

I'm not sure which ORM you are using, but if you really want to read immediately from the database while the transaction is still ongoing, you might consider something similar to `saveAndFlush`.
Please go through this document to fully understand why its still reading stall data:

- [Spring Transaction Management: @Transactional In-Depth](https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-transaction-management-transactional-in-depth)

Comment: I understand how Transactional works. I am eager to know why executing the procedure that creates a new entity and calling the read database function in the same transaction works, whereas executing an update procedure and calling the read function doesn't.

Comment: if you are using optimistic lock strategy of the ORM, and forgot to update the column used for it, the ORM may consider the row has not been updated and then return the cached one.